# SQL doesn't update when between files

Tags: python, mysql, sql, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot for discord using discord.py.

I ran into a problem. I have a command files, linked with cog. If I run an insert query in one file, and try to access it in another, it won't work, I have to restart the bot so it will refresh it, and get the new data. Is there anything I can do about it?

This is the code for inserting the data in one file:

```
Cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Table (UserID) VALUES (%s)", (ID))
Database.commit()
```

This is the code for getting the data in another file:

```
Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Table")
for User in Table:
    # Code...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the mysql connector module? If so it shouldn't matter what files are accessing the database as long as a connection is made and logged in. https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: Yes I am, I am inserting it in one file and right after that loading it from another.

Comment: is the second file using a new connection, or one that has been open for a time already?  If the latter, you need to `commit` before executing the `SELECT`, so that the changes made by the first file are visible.

Comment: In every file i have a new connection, and i did commit before the select.